# xts subsetting giving incorrect results for quarters

Tags: r, time-series, xts, forecasting

I'm trying to specify 1985Q2 to 1989Q2 but the result gives 1985Q3 to 1989Q3 even though I'm specifying April as the beginning month and June for the ending month.

```
xts.test <- xts(rnorm(440*12, mean=0, sd=10), order.by=timeBasedSeq(155001/1989))
xts.test<-to.quarterly(xts.test)

xts.s<-xts.test["1985-04/1989-06"]
```

Comment: I'm getting Q3-Q3 as expected.

Comment: Right. But I want to Q2-Q2. Q2 starts in April hence I set the start to April but it ends up starting from July, Q3.